# How to use Hammer in angular universal

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

Can anyone pls help me to fix hammer error

```
})(window, document, 'Hammer');
^
 ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object._MAP.8 (/Users/ks89/git/universal-starter/dist/server.js:126460:4)
```

in angular universal.

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unclear where you encounter this error. Usually you should stay away from scripts that access DOM directly on server side, especially Hammer because it's of no use on server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import `hammer` from `main.ts`, not directly from the module. That way, it won't be included server side

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md#step-5-gesture-support

Comment: Any examples? The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Just do `import 'hammerjs;` in the `main.ts` file. But I'm not sure this is still relevant with newest versions of material

Comment: I used event listeners in the end.